# create multiple comments for each user with faker php library model factories

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I want to generate fake data with faker PHP library but I want for example create 3 comments for each user. How should I do this?

I do create 1 comment for each user with this code :

```
factory(App\User::class, 50)->create()->each(function ($u) {
    $u->comments()->save(factory(App\Comment::class)->make());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :)

I used `dd(factory(Comment::class,mt_rand(0,3))->make())` and I found that it returns the collection of 3 comments that is been created so I used foreach to create all of these 3 comments for my user using these lines of code :

```
$comments = factory(Comment::class,mt_rand(0,3))->make();
  for ($i=0; $i < $comments->count(); $i++) { 
  $u->comments()->save($comments[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something like this:

```
factory(App\User::class, 50)->create()->each(function ($u) {
    $u->comments()->saveMany(factory(App\Comment::class, 3)->make());
});
```

> *In case you want to create more than one comment, use `->saveMany()` instead of `->save()`. `->save()` takes in an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` while `->saveMany()` an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` which is what `factory(App\Comment::class, 3)->make()` returns.*
>
> **Note**: I would randomize the number using `rand(1, 5)`.